# pandas to_sql failing after updated pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I updated pandas from .20 to .23 recently, and now a script that would insert a pandas DataFrame to sql (MS SQL Server) fails.  The frame is the same as it always has been (it's read from sql using pandas read_sql_table, and then just written back, solely as a test to make sure things are working).  I haven't changed any drivers, e.g. odbc, and I tested across a few drivers that worked for me prior to the update.  After the failure, I updated sqlalchemy, but this hasn't helped.

I get this error:

```
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains 6039 parameter markers, but 137111 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')   [SQL: 'INSERT INTO dbo.test_python_drop_write_append (various column names here) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
```

There are actual dataframe values farther down, but I didn't include them here. 
 The question marks are odd-looking and I can't explain them.  When I print the head of the dataframe, it looks just fine, and as I stated, it's the exact same dataframe that pandas has been reading and rewriting to sql in this test script successfully before.  I don't even know what a parameter marker is, and I'm not trying to explicitly specify anything related to them.

The writing code is this, and it's using the same sqlcon object that successfully reads data:

```
dataf.to_sql(name=tablename, con=sqlcon, schema=schemaname, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

I'm hoping an edit might get me some more attention, and I have some more information.  I tried looking through sql alchemy code to no avail.  I was trying to figure out exactly how the "insert (columns) values ()" statement is being created.  That did not work, but I did notice that all of the values look like this (?,?,?,?,...?,?), but then all of the actual values are being passed as parameters.  So, the sql statement looks like this:

```
     [SQL: 'INSERT INTO [dbname].[schemaname].[tablename] ([var1], [var2], [var3], [var4], [var5], [var6]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (actualdata1, actualdata2, etc.)]
```

The actual data aren't separated by () per row of data.  Anyway, any help in how to fix this would be appreciated.  Some change in pandas from 0.20 to 0.23 made this happen.  My data have some column names as numbers, and some columns that are populated entirely with pandas None.

Comment: Fixed (for me, anyway) with 0.23.1.  This thread provides some explanation: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21103